# Printing variables when debugging - gdb can not print variables calculated in another subroutine

Tags: debugging, gdb, fortran

I am currently debugging a code written in fortran and compiled with gfortran.

I have been facing problems to print some variables with gdb.

For example, when I am inside of a subroutine and I want to print a variable which comes from "outside" and has a size which depends of a parameter calculated in another subroutine, it looks like gdb doesn't recognize the size of the matrix and can't print it.

I give below a simplified example so that it is clear :

```
subroutine stiff(id)  
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)  
common /a/nnp  
dimension id(5,nnp)
```

Here are some results given by gdb

```
(gdb) print id  
$6 = ()  
(gdb) whatis id  
type = integer(kind=4) (5,0)  
(gdb) print nnp  
$7 = 15
```

Is there a way to fix this or is it inherent to the way of programming? This code has been developed by someone else and is huge, so I can change all the way of declaring variables.
Thanks in advance for any help.

edit :

See below a simple program (the most simple I could). It has globally the same structure as the code I am working on and the same behaviour with gdb that I described previously. When being into the input subroutine I can't print the "id" variable.

```
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
dimension a(1000)
call markaz(a)
stop
end

subroutine markaz(a)

implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
dimension a(1000)    
common /a/nnn

call dim1(l1,l2)

call input(a(l1))

return
end

subroutine dim1(l1,l2)
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
common /a/nnn     

print*, 'enter nnn:  ';read(*,*) nnn

l1=1
l2=l1+(nnn*5+1)/2

return
end

subroutine input(id)
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
common /a/nnn     
dimension id(5,nnn)

do i=1,5
do j=1,nnn 
id(i,j)=1.0
enddo
enddo

return
end
```

Here is what I get with gfortran 4.4.5 and gdb 7.0.1

```
$ gfortran -g -fbacktrace test.for  
$ gdb ./a.out  
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.0.1-debian  
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>  
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"  
and "show warranty" for details.  
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".  
For bug reporting instructions, please see:  
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...  
Reading symbols from /test_print/a.out...done.  
(gdb) break test.for :36  
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400a7d: file test.for, line 36.  
(gdb) run  
Starting program: /test_print/a.out   
 enter nnn:    
2  

Breakpoint 1, input (id=...) at test.for:37  
37        do i=1,5  
Current language:  auto  
The current source language is "auto; currently fortran".  
(gdb) whatis id  
type = integer(kind=4) (5,0)  
(gdb) print id  
$1 = ()  
(gdb) print nnn  
$2 = 2  
(gdb)
```

Comment: I tried it and my gdb printed the right answer. Could you add more details? Maybe some minimal test program?

Answer (score -1):

For me your code works well with gdb. Tested with gfortran 4.5.5 and gdb 7.2. It should not be any inherent limitation of that style of programming.

```
[testy]$ gfortran -g -fbacktrace common2.f90

[testy]$ gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-48.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/x/f/testy/a.out...done.
(gdb) break common2.f90:73
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400a2d: file common2.f90, line 73.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/x/f/testy/a.out 
 enter nnn:  
4

Breakpoint 1, input (id=...) at common2.f90:73
73      do i=1,5
(gdb) whatis id
type = integer(kind=4) (5,4)
(gdb) print id
$1 = (( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) )
(gdb) print nnn
$2 = 4
(gdb)
```

Comment: Doing exactly the same thing as you, see what I get in the edit of my post. So, can it be due to the versions of gfortran and gdb? Or is it a complete mystery?

Comment: It might be due to the different versions. Probably more problem of gdb, but also your version of gfortran is quite old.

Comment: to update this with gfortran 4.6.2 and gdb 7.3.1: gfortran first complains about the type of `id` (should be declared as `real*8`, and after fixing that gdb reports the type of id as `type = real(kind=8) (5,*)`

Comment: That's strange. It should not be real*8, but integer, because of implicit typing.